# Aggregate group inside group in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, grouping, aggregates

With `aggregate` I retrieve all my data grouped by day, this way:

```
db.collection('checkpoint').aggregate
[
    { '$match': {'id_journey': journey.id_journey} },
    { '$sort': { 'when': 1} },
    {
         '$group': {
             '_id': { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$when' } },
             'day': {                                    
                 '$push': {
                     'id': '$id_checkpoint',
                     'when': '$when',
                     'type': '$type',
                     'url_media': '$url_media'
                 }
             }
         }
    },  
    { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } },
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'day': 1
        }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    res.json(result);   
});
```

and the result is:

```
[{
    _id: "2016-04-22",
    day: [{
        id: "c571be034449bee845f2b43211",
        when: "2016-04-22T20:51:00.190Z",
        type: "picture",
        url_media: "my_photo_1.jpg"
    }]
}, {
    _id: "2016-04-23",
    day: [{
        id: "c571be034449bee845f2b43222",
        when: "2016-04-23T20:50:00.190Z",
        type: "picture",
        url_media: "my_photo_2.jpg"
    }, {
        id: "c571be034449bee845f2b43233",
        when: "2016-04-23T20:51:00.190Z",
        type: "picture",
        url_media: "my_photo_3.jpg"
    }]
}]
```

that's correct.

But what if I need to grouping for hour (using the `$hour` [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) of MongoDB) inside each day?
The wanted result is that each day-group is subdivided in groups of hours: it's possible?

Comment: An example of how you would want your output to loo would be helpful

Comment: may be this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318623/2782784

Comment: @achuth exactly, thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. First you have to project hour. Now you have hour field in aggregation pipeline. You can easily group on the hour field